# Draw circles in CSS or use .pngs?

Tags: css, background

I was wondering what's the best option to add the circles I have in my design here. Initially I just saved the background circles as a .png and slapped that in there, underneath everything else - but what's the best practice? Should I draw them in CSS?

[image: image of my design]

Comment: looks fine to me.

Comment: It depends. If you want something easy, it can stay like it is right now because it's prettly good. But if you want performance, you would need to use some css to position circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your design, it seems that you will need to import some images, so my opinion is to cut the circles with the actual image (not two different files).

If there was no actual image, I would suggest drawing them with CSS since that would mean fewer calls to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `border-radius` in css, for that , for example :

```css
border-bottom-right-radius: $size * 2;
border-top-right-radius: $size * 2;
```